# tensorflow: how to set the shape of tensor with different conditional statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to train a network with two different shapes of input tensor. Each epoch chooses one type.
Here I write a small code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


with tf.Session() as sess:

    imgs1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [4, 224, 224, 3], name = 'input_imgs1')
    imgs2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [4, 180, 180, 3], name = 'input_imgs2')
    epoch_num_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], name = 'input_epoch_num')

    imgs = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.mod(epoch_num_tf, 2), 0), 
                lambda: tf.Print(imgs2, [imgs2.get_shape()], message='(even number) input epoch number is '),
                lambda: tf.Print(imgs1, [imgs1.get_shape()], message='(odd number) input epoch number is'))


    print(imgs.get_shape())


    for epoch in range(10):
        epoch_num = np.array(epoch).astype(np.int32)
        imgs1_input = np.ones([4, 224, 224, 3], dtype = np.float32)
        imgs2_input = np.ones([4, 180, 180, 3], dtype = np.float32)

        output = sess.run(imgs, feed_dict = {epoch_num_tf: epoch_num,
                                          imgs1: imgs1_input,
                                          imgs2: imgs2_input})
```

When I execute it, the output of `imgs.get_shape()` is `(4, ?, ?, 3)`
i.e. `imgs.get_shape()[1]=None, imgs.get_shape()[2]=None`.

But I will use the value of the output of `imgs.get_shape()` to define the kernel (`ksize`) and strides size (`strides`) of the `tf.nn.max_pool()` e.g. `ksize=[1,imgs.get_shape()[1]/6, imgs.get_shape()[2]/6, 1]` in the future code. 
I think `ksize` and `strides` cannot support `tf.Tensor` value.

How to solve this problem? Or how to set the shape of `imgs` conditionally?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `print(a.get_shape())`, you are getting the **static shape** of the tensor `a`. Assuming you mean `imgs.get_shape()` and not `a.get_shape()` in the code above, dimensions 1 and 2 of `imgs` vary dynamically with the value of `epoch_num_tf`. Therefore the static shape in those dimensions is unknown, which TensorFlow represents as `None`.

If you want to use the **dynamic shape** of `imgs` in subsequent code, you should use the [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) operator to get the shape as a `tf.Tensor`. For example, instead of `imgs.get_shape()[2]`, you can use `tf.shape(imgs)[2]`.

Unfortunately, the `ksize` and `strides` arguments of [`tf.nn.max_pool()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#max_pool) do not accept `tf.Tensor` values. (I think this is a historical limitation, because these were configured as "attrs" rather than "inputs" of the corresponding kernel. Please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) if you'd like to request this feature!) One possible workaround would be to use another `tf.cond()`:

```
imgs = ...

# Could also use `tf.equal(tf.mod(epoch_num_tf, 2), 0)` as the predicate.
pool_output = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(imgs)[2], 180),
                      lambda: tf.nn.max_pool(imgs, ksize=[1, 180/6, 180/6, 1], ...),
                      lambda: tf.nn.max_pool(imgs, ksize=[1, 224/6, 224/6, 1], ...))
```

Comment: I changed from `a` to `imgs` in the question. To be specific, the value from `get_shape()` will be used for the input of kernel size (e.g. `ksize=[1, imgs.get_shape()[1]/6, imgs.get_shape()[2]/6, 1`) and stride size (`strides`) of the `tf.nn.max_pool()` I think it should input the normal int value which should cannot support tf.Tensor. Is it possible to do that?